# Cómo obtener valores por horas en una fecha con mysql y php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, registro

Tengo una base de datos con una columna fecha_datos de tipo timestamp donde se almacena datos cada 30 segundos, lo que yo quiero mostrar son los datos de un día cualquiera, por hora desde las 00hs hasta las 23hs? o sea:

tomar datos cada una hora de estos horarios:|

00:00, 01:00, 03:00, 04:00, 05:00, 06:00, 07:00, 08:00, 09:00,...... ETC.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

dejo la gráfica para que vean que es lo que quiero hacer.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Podrías [edit] tu pregunta y agregar lo que llevas hecho? Así como esta, pareciera que estas pidiendo que hagan tu trabajo. Compartí lo que llevas hecho así podemos ayudarte.

Comment: Estaría bien también que agregues la estructura básica de tu tabla así como unos datos básicos de ejemplo para pruebas. Un saludo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obtener la instantánea con una tupla para minuto cero y segundo cero:

```
SELECT hour(fecha_datos) hora
     , ppm_datos
  FROM tabla
  WHERE fecha_datos between '2021-05-21 00:00:00' and '2021-05-21 23:59:59'
    AND (minute(fecha_datos),second(fecha_datos)) = (0,0)
```

Comment: Esto es lo que quería pero al hacer lo que dijiste me encontré con un inconveniente que si no hay un dato en ese lugar quisiera que me mostrara el siguiente para que siempre la salida sean 24 datos.

Answer (score 0):

Para poder obtener la estadística por horas primero necesitamosa agrupoar los registro en base a la hora para ello podemos utilizar la función `HOUR` y para poder obtener las filas en las horas en las que no tenemos tengamos registros necesitaremos tener una tabla virtual o una tabla catálogo con las horas.

### Ejemplo

#### Definiendo la estructura

Primero definamos una tabla y un set de datos para pruebas:

```sql
-- Tabla
CREATE TABLE `test` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `value` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp() ON UPDATE current_timestamp(),
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

-- Insertar datos
INSERT INTO `test` (`value`, `created_at`) VALUES ('5', '2021-05-24 13:02:00');

INSERT INTO `test` (`value`, `created_at`) VALUES ('1', '2021-05-24 17:13:00');

INSERT INTO `test` (`value`, `created_at`) VALUES ('8', '2021-05-24 20:02:00');
INSERT INTO `test` (`value`, `created_at`) VALUES ('1', '2021-05-24 20:10:00');

INSERT INTO `test` (`value`, `created_at`) VALUES ('2', '2021-05-24 21:02:00');
INSERT INTO `test` (`value`, `created_at`) VALUES ('1', '2021-05-24 21:25:00');
INSERT INTO `test` (`value`, `created_at`) VALUES ('4', '2021-05-24 21:30:00');
```

#### Agrupando los datos por horas

Ahora podemos realizar nuestra consulta filtrando por la fecha y agrupando por la hora sobre la columna `created_at`

```sql
-- Utilizamos la funcion HOUR() para obtener la hora de la fecha y con SUM sumamos los valores de la columna value
SELECT HOUR(test.created_at) hora, SUM(test.value) total
FROM test
WHERE
    -- En el where filtramos por la fecha que nos interesa
    DATE(test.created_at) = '2021-05-24'
    -- Y agrupamos los registros que pertenecen a la misma hora
    GROUP BY HOUR(test.created_at);
```

Resultado:

```
| hora | total |
|------|-------|
|   13 |     5 |
|   17 |     1 |
|   20 |     9 |
|   21 |     7 |
```

Como vemos obtenemos los registros por horas sumando los valores. El problema de esto es que las horas en las que no hay registros no aparecen y generalmente en este tipo de consultas destinadas a gráficas nos interesa mostrar en las horas que no hay registros un valor de `0` por ejemplo.

Para solventar el problema podemos añadir una tabla catálogo con la que cruzar los datos haciendo un JOIN.

#### Obtener también las horas que no tienen datos

Primero añadamos nuestra tabla de horas y sus valores:

```sql
-- Crear tabla de horas
CREATE TABLE `hour` (
 `hour` time NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`hour`)
);

-- Insertar horas
INSERT INTO `hours` (`hour`) VALUES
('00:00:01'),
('01:00:00'),
('02:00:00'),
('03:00:00'),
('04:00:00'),
('05:00:00'),
('06:00:00'),
('07:00:00'),
('08:00:00'),
('09:00:00'),
('10:00:00'),
('11:00:00'),
('12:00:00'),
('13:00:00'),
('14:00:00'),
('15:00:00'),
('16:00:00'),
('17:00:00'),
('18:00:00'),
('19:00:00'),
('20:00:00'),
('21:00:00'),
('22:00:00'),
('23:00:00');
```

Una vez tenemos nuestra tabla catálogo podemos hacer un JOIN para obtener siempre una fila por cada hora:

Ejemplo:

```
SELECT
    -- Seleccionamos la hora de nuestra tabla hours
    HOUR(hours.hour) hora,
    -- añadimos un condicional para que si el valor es null lo establezca como 0
    IF(v.total, v.total, 0) total
FROM hours
-- creamos el join con una subquery a nuestra tabla test y le damos el alias `v`
-- En esta caso un LEFT para que siempre traiga el lado izquierdo (hours)
LEFT JOIN
    (
        -- La consulta es igual que antes
        SELECT HOUR(test.created_at) hora, SUM(test.value) total
        FROM test
        WHERE
            DATE(test.created_at) = '2021-05-24'
            GROUP BY HOUR(test.created_at)
    ) v
    -- Unimos el join por las horas que son iguales en nuestra consulta y en la tabla hours
    ON HOUR(hours.hour) = v.hora 
-- Ordenamos por orden ascendente
ORDER BY hora ASC;
```

Resultado:

```
| hora | total |
|------|-------|
|    0 |     0 |
|    1 |     0 |
|    2 |     0 |
|    3 |     0 |
|    4 |     0 |
|    5 |     0 |
|    6 |     0 |
|    7 |     0 |
|    8 |     0 |
|    9 |     0 |
|   10 |     0 |
|   11 |     0 |
|   12 |     0 |
|   13 |     5 |
|   14 |     0 |
|   15 |     0 |
|   16 |     0 |
|   17 |     1 |
|   18 |     0 |
|   19 |     0 |
|   20 |     9 |
|   21 |     7 |
|   22 |     0 |
|   23 |     0 |
```

---

### Extra

- Ejemplo en acción: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3b2f40/5/0
- [Documentación mysql HOUR](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_hour)